# Issues with execvp() and incomplete multi-argument commands

Tags: c, exec, system-calls

I'm using execvp() to run some system calls. Program works great for valid commands, and fails for any command that doesn't exist, which is perfect.
The program is, when I use execvp() on a command that needs extra arguments(like cat) and I don't provide arguments, the program just infinitely reads from input.

I'm not sure how to get around this issue, as I don't know how to 'tell' if a command is incomplete. Any ideas?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        char command[1000];


        printf("Enter command: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]s", command);

        char *temp = strtok(command, " ");
        char *commandList[100];
        int index = 0;

        while (temp != NULL) {
                commandList[index] = temp;
                index++;

                temp = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }

        commandList[index] = NULL;

        execvp(commandList[0], commandList);

        printf("Failed");
}
```

The ideal result would be a print of "Command incomplete" and the process ending.

Comment: If the program you are starting never needs to read from `stdin`, why don't you just close it before `execvp()`?

Comment: The common way to avoid commands from reading from `stdin` is to open `STDIN_FILENO` to `/dev/null`

Comment: @EOF — one reason for not simply closing standard input is that programs are entitled to assume that standard input, standard output and standard error are opened appropriately.  Redirecting standard input so it comes from `/dev/null` is a much better idea than simply closing standard input.

Comment: Note that `cat` does not require any extra arguments; when it is invoked with no arguments, it reads up to EOF on standard input.  It is working exactly as designed.  It would be best to report errors on `stderr` instead of `stdout`; it would be best to include the failed command name in the error message (in case it wasn't what the user thought they typed); it would be best to finish the error message with a newline (`fprintf(stderr, "Failed (%s)\n", commandList[0]);`).

Comment: Oh, and when a program fails, it should exit or return a non-zero exit code (either `EXIT_FAILURE` from `<stdlib.h>`, or conventionally `1`).  That lets the calling code (shell or whatever) know it was not successful.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler While some may argue that corporations have the right to free speech, I'm quite sure that *programs* are "entitled" to absolutely nothing. The *user* has the right to run the program with `stdin` closed if they so please (for example if they find that the program crashing/misbehaving is preferable to it reading from `stdin`).

Comment: It’s the C standard that stipulates the right I articulated on behalf of C programs,@EOF.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ideas from the comment completely answered my question (To the exact needs I had). Not sure how to give him credit on here, though.

The solution is to simply close stdin right before I use execvp(). If the command is not completed on the first scanf, the program throws an error, which is perfect.
Since I'm running the main program I'm using this on in a loop, I can use dup and dup2 to save and reload stdin later.

The code I used to test if it'll work:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        char command[1000];

        int stdinput = dup(STDIN_FILENO);

        close(STDIN_FILENO);

        dup2(stdinput, STDIN_FILENO);


        printf("Enter command: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]s", command);


        printf("%s\n", command);
}
```